# ERROR: this.props.addNew is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I'm new to react and Ive been playing around with it for the past few weeks. I keep on getting this **"ERROR: this.props.addNew is not a function"** error about the addNew function within the addTheFriend function and I dont know why? Everything seems to correct to me. Can anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';

    export default class HelloUser extends React.Component {


        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { name: "TT", friendsCount: 0 , friends: ["SS", "JJ", "Ww"] };
          this.addFriends=this.addFriends.bind(this);
          this.componentWillMount=this.componentWillMount.bind(this);

        }


      addFriends(friend) {
        this.setState({
          friends: this.state.friends.concat([friend]),
          friendsCount: this.state.friendsCount + 1
        });
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
          friendsCount: this.state.friends.length
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            Villain: {this.state.name}, No of friends: {this.state.friendsCount}<br />
            <AddingTheFriend addNew={this.addFriends} />
            <ListFriends enemies={this.state.friends} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

    export default class ListFriends extends React.Component {

      render() {
        var allFriends = this.props.enemies.map(function (friend) {
          return <li>{friend}</li>;
        });

        return (
          <div>
            Her evil friends:
            <ul>{allFriends}</ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

    export default class AddingTheFriend extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state= {newFriend: ''};
          this.updateNewFriend = this.updateNewFriend.bind(this);
          this.addTheFriend = this.addTheFriend.bind(this);
        }


      updateNewFriend(change) {
        this.setState({
          newFriend: change.target.value
        });
      }

      addTheFriend() {
        this.props.addNew(this.state.newFriend);
        this.setState({
          newFriend: ''
        })
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.newFriend} onChange={this.updateNewFriend} />
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addTheFriend}>Add Friend</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    };

    render(<HelloUser />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Copy pasted your code into a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5z5qj7x6mk), removed the export statements because it is all in one file and it works.

Comment: Side Observation: You don't have to bind `componentWillMount` to `this`

Comment: @KyleRichardson Oh woow that makes me feel really dumb lol..Thank you man

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Did not know that, thank you

Comment: @firmfiasco We've all been there? And you're welcome.